# Android: Restart the app if reached the max heap size

Tags: android, performance

Is there a better way to restart the app if the app reached the max heap size or if its already greater than to my specific heap size it will restart the app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good practice to reset all the unwanted object (release the memory) on **onTrimMemory()** callback in **Application** class rather then restarting the application.